# Dhcpcd not assigning IPV6 address to LAN Interface

Tags: routing, ipv6, dhcpv6, ip6tables, dhcpcd

I am trying to use Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W as an IPV6 router having a debian based os. I have a usb wifi adapter (Interface Wlan1 ) facing wan . The inbuilt wifi (Wlan0) is facing LAN with hostapd running on this interface . I have no problem with IPV4 , everything works fine .LAN clients get IPV4 address . But the system if unable to provide IPV6 address to the LAN clients.

**To me the problem seems to be with dhcpcd settings , as pi receives router advertisement with ipv6 prefix and assigns IPV6 address to wlan1 but doesn't assign any IPV6 address to wlan0 (LAN interface) .**

Here is my dhcpcd.conf :

```
hostname
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private
debug
logfile /home/pi/dhcpcd.log
noipv6rs
waitip 6
interface wlan1
        option rapid_commit
        ipv6rs
        ia_na 0
        ia_pd 1 wlan0/0
interface wlan0
        nohook wpa_supplicant
        nogateway
        static ip_address=10.10.0.1/24
        static routers=10.10.0.0
        static domain_name_servers=8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

hostapd.conf

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211

hw_mode=g
channel=6
ieee80211n=1
wmm_enabled=1
ht_capab=[HT40][SHORT-GI-20][DSSS_CCK-40]
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP

ssid=*******
wpa_passphrase=*******
```

dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=wlan0       # Use interface wlan1
listen-address=10.10.0.1   # Specify the address to listen on
#bind-interfaces      # Bind to the interface
server=8.8.8.8       # Use Google DNS
domain-needed        # Don't forward short names
bogus-priv           # Drop the non-routed address spaces.
dhcp-range=10.10.0.50,10.10.0.150,12h # IP range and lease time
```

**To me the problem seems to be with dhcpcd settings , as pi receives router advertisement with ipv6 prefix and assigns IPV6 address to wlan1 but doesn't assign any IPV6 address to wlan0 (LAN interface) .** Here is dhcpcd log :

```
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: dhcpcd-8.1.2 starting
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: udev: starting
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: dev: loaded udev
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' PREINIT
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: connected to Access Point `'
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' CARRIER
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan1: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' PREINIT
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan1: connected to Access Point `'
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan1: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' NOCARRIER
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: DUID 00:01:00:01:2d:01:4e:61:d8:3a:dd:65:09:0b
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: IAID dd:65:09:0b
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: using ClientID 01:d8:3a:dd:65:09:0b
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: using static address 10.10.0.1/24
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: adding IP address 10.10.0.1/24 broadcast 10.10.0.255
Jan 31 14:17:46 [1439]: wlan0: adding route to 10.10.0.0/24
Jan 31 14:17:47 [1439]: wlan0: ARP announcing 10.10.0.1 (1 of 2), next in 2.0 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:47 [1439]: wlan0: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' STATIC
Jan 31 14:17:47 [1439]: waiting for an IPv6 address
Jan 31 14:17:47 [1439]: wlan1: waiting for carrier
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan0: ARP announcing 10.10.0.1 (2 of 2)
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: carrier acquired
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: connected to Access Point `XXXXXX'
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' CARRIER
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: IAID 24:8f:8d:b2
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: IA type 3 IAID 00:00:00:00
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: IA type 25 IAID 00:00:00:01
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: adding address fe80::5fd5:83b1:4372:ecbb
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: pltime infinity, vltime infinity
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: delaying IPv6 router solicitation for 0.7 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: delaying DHCPv6 soliciation for LL address
Jan 31 14:17:49 [1439]: wlan1: delaying IPv4 for 0.5 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: using ClientID 01:00:e0:24:8f:8d:b2
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: reading lease `/var/lib/dhcpcd/wlan1-XXXXXX.lease'
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: rebinding lease of 192.168.191.210
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: ARP announcing 192.168.191.210 (1 of 2), next in 2.0 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: sending REQUEST (xid 0x302bcf59), next in 3.8 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: acknowledged 192.168.191.210 from 192.168.191.185
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: leased 192.168.191.210 for 3600 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: renew in 1800 seconds, rebind in 3150 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: writing lease `/var/lib/dhcpcd/wlan1-XXXXXX.lease'
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: adding IP address 192.168.191.210/24 broadcast 192.168.191.255
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: adding route to 192.168.191.0/24
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: adding default route via 192.168.191.185
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: ARP announcing 192.168.191.210 (1 of 2), next in 2.0 seconds
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' REBOOT
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: waiting for an IPv6 address
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: soliciting an IPv6 router
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: delaying Router Solicitation for LL address
Jan 31 14:17:50 [1439]: wlan1: bound, ignoring 192.168.191.210 from 192.168.191.185
Jan 31 14:17:52 [1439]: wlan1: ARP announcing 192.168.191.210 (2 of 2)
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: reading lease `/var/lib/dhcpcd/wlan1-XXXXXX.lease6'
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: soliciting a DHCPv6 lease
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: delaying SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 0.3 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: sending Router Solicitation
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: Router Advertisement from fe80::947c:b8ff:fe17:80
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: adding address 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e:92c3:fe06:2398:8026/64
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: pltime 3600 seconds, vltime 3600 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: adding route to 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::/64
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: adding default route via fe80::947c:b8ff:fe17:80
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: waiting for Router Advertisement DAD to complete
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: No DHCPv6 instruction in RA
Jan 31 14:18:00 [1439]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 0.9 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:01 [1439]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 1.8 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:02 [1439]: wlan1: Router Advertisement from fe80::947c:b8ff:fe17:80
Jan 31 14:18:02 [1439]: wlan1: adding address 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e:92c3:fe06:2398:8026/64
Jan 31 14:18:02 [1439]: wlan1: pltime 3600 seconds, vltime 3600 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:02 [1439]: wlan1: waiting for Router Advertisement DAD to complete
Jan 31 14:18:02 [1439]: wlan1: No DHCPv6 instruction in RA
Jan 31 14:18:03 [1439]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 3.7 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:07 [1439]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 7.1 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:11 [1439]: wlan1: Router Advertisement DAD completed
Jan 31 14:18:11 [1439]: wlan1: executing `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-run-hooks' ROUTERADVERT
Jan 31 14:18:11 [1439]: forking to background
Jan 31 14:18:11 [1493]: wlan1: sending NA for 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e:92c3:fe06:2398:8026/64
Jan 31 14:18:11 [1439]: forked to background, child pid 1493
Jan 31 14:18:12 [1493]: wlan1: sending NA for 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e:92c3:fe06:2398:8026/64
Jan 31 14:18:13 [1493]: wlan1: sending NA for 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e:92c3:fe06:2398:8026/64
Jan 31 14:18:14 [1493]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 14.0 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:28 [1493]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 27.7 seconds
Jan 31 14:18:55 [1493]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 55.2 seconds
Jan 31 14:19:51 [1493]: wlan1: broadcasting SOLICIT6 (xid 0x90602f), next in 109.9 seconds
```

Here is tcpdump of router advertisement received to wlan1 (sudo tcpdump -vvvv -ttt -i wlan1 icmp6 and 'ip6[40] = 134' ) :

```
        hop limit 63, Flags [none], pref high, router lifetime 3600s, reachable time 0ms, retrans timer 0ms
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 96:7c:b8:17:00:80
            0x0000:  967c b817 0080
          mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1500
            0x0000:  0000 0000 05dc
          prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 3600s, pref. time 3600s
            0x0000:  40c0 0000 0e10 0000 0e10 0000 0000 2409
            0x0010:  4052 8e17 343e 0000 0000 0000 0000
          rdnss option (25), length 24 (3):  lifetime 3600s, addr: 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::86
            0x0000:  0000 0000 0e10 2409 4052 8e17 343e 0000
            0x0010:  0000 0000 0086
 00:00:02.443370 IP6 (flowlabel 0x9275e, hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 88) fe80::947c:b8ff:fe17:80 > ip6-allnodes: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router advertisement, length 88
        hop limit 63, Flags [none], pref high, router lifetime 3600s, reachable time 0ms, retrans timer 0ms
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 96:7c:b8:17:00:80
            0x0000:  967c b817 0080
          mtu option (5), length 8 (1):  1500
            0x0000:  0000 0000 05dc
          prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 3600s, pref. time 3600s
            0x0000:  40c0 0000 0e10 0000 0e10 0000 0000 2409
            0x0010:  4052 8e17 343e 0000 0000 0000 0000
          rdnss option (25), length 24 (3):  lifetime 3600s, addr: 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::86
            0x0000:  0000 0000 0e10 2409 4052 8e17 343e 0000
            0x0010:  0000 0000 0086
```

Please Help .

Comment: Is the upstream configured to hand out routed subnets via DHCP (prefix delegation)?

Comment: Thanks vidarlo for your reply . 
    The upstream is an ISP provided router . But it seems from tcpdump of router advertisement that a prefix of length 64 is being provided :
```
prefix info option (3), length 32 (4): 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::/64, Flags [onlink, auto], valid time 3600s, pref. time 3600s
```
part of ip address has been masked by me .

Comment: /64 is a normal subnet for IPv6. You need (and request) Prefix Delegation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the `radvd` binary installed, for example by running `which radvd` getting a non-empty string, such as `/usr/bin/radvd`. Install it as needed.

Try adding the required address manually (wlan0 is the LAN-facing interface, change the IP back to the one you saw in tcpdump, don't forget the `1` after the colons). This command needs to be run at every startup:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/accept_ra
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/accept_dad
ip addr add 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::1/64 dev wlan0
```

(The lines starting with `echo` provide basic hardening against misconfigured clients who might knock your router out of the network.)

Then remove the attempted config to get DHCPv6 working for now and just get radvd working first. You'll need radvd anyway even if you eventually deploy DHCPv6, so limit the possibility for mistakes. Create `radvd.conf` with this content and run it with `radvd -C /etc/radvd.conf start`:

```
interface wlan0 {
   MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
   MaxRtrAdvInterval 4;
   AdvLinkMTU 1500;
   AdvSendAdvert on;
   MinDelayBetweenRAs 3;
   prefix 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::/64 {
    AdvOnLink on;
    AdvAutonomous on;
    AdvValidLifetime 86400;
    AdvPreferredLifetime 86400;
   };
   RDNSS 2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::1 {
    AdvRDNSSLifetime 86400;
   };
   DNSSL local {
    FlushDNSSL on;
   };
};
```

Change `2409:XXXX:XXXX:343e::` and `wlan0` to your actual values, optionally customize `local` to a word that is different from any TLD; popular choices include `lan` and `home`.

Try accessing IPv6 content from the clients behind the router first - it's a common issue that the router itself is unable to use the IPv6 connection while the users can. It's when the WAN IP is not public. To work around this, you need to tell the router to use the LAN IP for all outgoing connections. There are several ways of configuring this, each applicable to a different subset of distros. Mine is `ip -6 route replace default via <GATEWAY> dev <WAN_IF> src <LAN_IPv6>`. So google around and see. One last advice though - there seems to be a race condition between the assignment of the IPv6 address and the possibility of changing the outgoing IP; I just use `sleep 2` between them.